# Object of objects always returning undefined with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects, each

Perhaps something silly, but I have this `status` JS object of objects (obtained with **console.log(status)**):

`{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 10: {…}}
1:
    error: true
    __proto__: Object
2:
    validated: false
    value: 0
    whitelist: false
    __proto__: Object
10:
    validated: false
    value: 0
    whitelist: false
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object`

Then I have:

`$.each( status, function( key, value ) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value)
});`

Which prints respectively `1`, `2` and `10` for keys and ...

`{}
    error: true
    __proto__: Object`

`{}
    validated: false
    value: 0
    whitelist: false
    __proto__: Object`

`{}
    validated: false
    value: 0
    whitelist: false
    __proto__: Object`

...for values. So far so good. But then, when I try to access any key **of the inner objects**, say, for example,

`$.each( status, function( key, value ) {
    console.log(value.validated);
    console.log(value['error'])
});`

... I get `undefined` in any case: using dot syntax, array syntax and so on.
Any idea?

**EDIT**: So weird, it is not because of `$.each` because doing a simple

`console.log(status[1]['error'])` returns `undefined` when `status[1]` keeps returning `{ error: true }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array contains different properties, therefore accessing the property `error` will return `undefined` because it does not exists in index 1 nor 2, only in 0.

```
$.each (status, function(i, item)
{
    if (item.error != undefined)
        // do something

    if (item.validated != undefined)
        // do something
});
```

Lastly, about your edit and as said in my first paragraph, the `error` property does not exists in index 1, so the following code should return the expected result.

`console.log(status[0].error);`

Comment: I know, but sorry: I am investigating all of this and it has to do with async functions in JS... `status` variable is filled within a callback, in an async function, so it is not ready yet when called. The weird thing is that if I do `console.log` of the whole `status` variable, it returns the filled and good one, always. However, when I `console.log` any of the nested objects, it always returns `undefined`...

If it was a matter of order of execution, no matter if `status` or `status[1]['owner']` would return undefined, isn't it??

Comment: Marked as the solution because I understand that with the provided information, your solution is correct. Thanks anyway @Linesofcode.